# Perl UTF8 in CGI problems

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi

I have a very simple Perl script which works right on the terminal but when run as a CGI script it produces garbage.  The script basically take a HTML entities encoded data and converts it to print it. I have tried all the different setup like using "Encode" to change the output and set the STDOUT to utf8 mode and it does not help. I have also tried to change the environment of CGI to see if things will work like the terminal environment.  Still no luck.

Here is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities_numeric decode_entities);
use Encode qw/encode decode/;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
#$ENV{'PERL_UNICODE'} = 'D';
#$ENV{'LANG'} = 'en_US.UTF-8';
#$ENV{'TERM'} = 'vt100';
#$ENV{'SHELL'} = '/bin/bash';
#binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $y = decode_entities("&#x3A3;&#x3C5;&#x3C3;&#x3C4;&#x3B7;&#x301;&#x3BC;&#x3B1;&#x3C4;&#x3B1;_&#x
391;&#x3BD;&#x3B9;&#x301;&#x3C7;&#x3BD;&#x3B5;&#x3C5;&#x3C3;&#x3B7;&#x3C2;_&#x395;&#x3B9;&#x3C3;.pd
f");
#print encode("UTF8",$y);
print $y;
```

The output on terminal it is clean like
perl test.pl
Content-type: text/html

Συστήματα_Ανίχνευσης_Εισ.pdf

But on the CGI print it is garbled
Î£Ï…ÏƒÏ„Î·ÌÎ¼Î±Ï„Î±_Î‘Î½Î¹ÌÏ‡Î½ÎµÏ…ÏƒÎ·Ï‚_Î•Î¹Ïƒ.pdf

I am sort of stuck as I cannot find any simple way to solve this.  Tried  "encode_utf8" and utf8::upgrade of the variable but still no luck.  Anyone's experience here will help a lot!

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When interpreting a HTML document, the browser needs to know the encoding. The default encoding as per the HTML standard is not UTF-8. Since the browser is assuming the wrong encoding, it reads garbage.

Instead, you should specify the encoding explicitly, such as by printing a meta tag

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

or by including the encoding in the content type:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Here, using the content type would seem most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @amon the display part works like you said.  But when I try to find the file in the local system with UTF-8 filename of Συστήματα_Ανίχνευσης_Εισ.pdf (which is Intrusion Detection System document in Greek) - it seems like the byte string from decode_entities does not match the filename!  It says file does not exist either for "-f" condition or for using "open"

Comment: @Vijay, Comments are not the place to ask new questions. Don't forget to include the specific contents of the variable passed to `open`, and the specific file name as returned by `readdir`. You can use `sprintf "%vX", $var` for that.